# Poker scénario preflop all in

Tags: poker-theory

Question: suppose 1 player all in preflop with 99 for 100$, players 2(AK) and 3(KQ)call:
-Flop is 9K6, p2 bet 200 p3 call..
-Turn 9k64, p2 bet again 500 and p3 call again.
-River 9k64A, p2 all in for 2000, p3 fold.
Now p1 win with 999 vs p2 with two pair AK.
Pot is over 3000$

So does that mean player 1 win all the money on the board ? Since he initially all in with only 100$ ? Or will the 2 players split the pot ? But how will it be calculated ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When a player is all-in player only gets action on the money, they are all in with, any action between other remaining players is in a side pot that the all-in player has no claim to.

Answer (score 0):

So player 1 only BET $100, so only has a claim to $100 of everyone else’s bets.

In your case, they would win $300 (called the main pot), and the other player who went all in would win $2700 (called the side pot).

I believe in most places, they would rake the main pot so it may be a bit less than $300.